# Scope true in directive giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular2-directives

I am using scope as 'true' in a directive. So now, this directive scope passes from parent to child, but not in reverse. I am printing now scope.name 2 times. First in parent scope, second in directive. Now I should get 2 different values. But, I am getting same scope value for both. Pl help explain!

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){

return{
 template: "{{name}}",
 scope:true
}
controller: [function(){
 $scope.name = "Roger"
}]

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

{{name}}, 

<my-student></my-student> 

</body> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is out of directive. I placed it inside and added `$scope` dependency. It works!

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){

return{
 template: "{{name}}",
 scope:true,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "Roger"
        }]
}


});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

{{name}}, 

<my-student></my-student> 

</body> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Runs perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @Deadpool please accept the answer if found helpful

Comment: There is time left.

Answer (score 1):

Write your controller inside of DDO.

```
//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){

return{
    template: "{{name}}",
    scope:true,
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.name = "Roger"
    }]
}
```

Probably, this will solve your problem.

Comment: BTW you also need to inject $scope to directive controller, else gives error. Also, whats full form of DDO?

Comment: @Deadpool, Thanks, I forgot that.

Comment: @Deadpool "Directive Definition Object"

Answer (score 0):

Easy make an object in parent controller so that it can be binded with directive
i.e var x={};
x.value=value;// that you want to pass then try accessing it.